# backbone + requirejs: scope issue

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have 2 views, one is a list of "timetracks" and the other is a form to create a timetrack/s
The first one has a collection attached.
The second one, the timetraks form, it defines a "create" function that makes reference to the first one to rerender timetraks view once a new timetrack is created.

timetracks code:

```
define(['backbone','collections/timetracks', 'views/timetracks/item'], function(Backbone, instanceTimeTracksCollection, TimeTrackView){
    var TimeTrackGrid = Backbone.View.extend({
        //......
    });
    return TimeTrackGrid;

});
```

The form code:

```
define(['backbone', 'collections/timetracks'], function(Backbone, instanceTimeTracksCollection){
    //...............
    //next comes my issue:
    create: function(){
        instanceTimeTracksCollection.create(indexed_array,{
            success: function(model, response) {
                console.info('model created, response = ',response);
                // timeTracksGrid is out of scope, timeTracksGrid would be an instance of timetracks.
                timeTracksGrid.render();
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.info('error=',error);
            },
            wait:true
        });
    }

});
```

... and finally I have app.js where the instances of both views are defined:

```
requirejs(['backbone','views/timetracks/new','views/timetracks/list'],
    function(Backbone, newTimeTrackForm, timeTracksGrid) {
        var grid = new timeTracksGrid();
        var formView = new newTimeTrackForm();
    });
```

How could I render the timetracks view once a new timetrack is created?

******************************** UPDATE *****************************************

This is my new version of the code. The issue now is that "this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);" is overlapping with "this.collection.fetch". As a result the timetracks records are rendered multiple times.

```
// timetracks view
define(['backbone','collections/timetracks', 'views/timetracks/item'], function(Backbone, timeTracksCollection, TimeTrackView){
    var TimeTrackGrid = Backbone.View.extend({
            //....
            initialize: function(){
                _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'generateTimeTracks', 'appendTimeTrack');
                this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
                this.render();
            }
            render: function(){
                $(this.el).html("<table border='1'></table>");
                this.collection.fetch({
                    success: this.generateTimeTracks
                });
           },
           generateTimeTracks : function(){
                var self = this;
                _(this.collection.models).each(function(item){ 
                    self.appendTimeTrack(item);
                }, this);
           },
           appendTimeTrack: function(item){
                var timeTrackView = new TimeTrackView({
                    model: item
                });
                $('table', this.el).append(timeTrackView.render().el);
           }

    }
```

Some other changes:

- on app.js instead doing {model:myCollection} as you suggested I'm doing {collection: myCollection}
- my form code creates a new model by calling this.collection.create

Thanks again !

Comment: have few questions : 1) "timetrack" is timetrack view or model ? 2) do you need to catch the event this should be created or rendered ? 3) do you have ability to update render() method in views and is it possible to use custom events ?

Comment: @Evgeniy, 
1) "timetracks" is a view.
2) Sorry, I don't understand this question
3) I thin I could...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different solution would be to create the views and your collection seperately.

Then in your app.js you could pass the collection to both views. In the initialize function of the `TimeTrackGrid` you should listen to the "add" event of models on the collections. When such an event is fired you should render the view.

In the create method of your form view you could add the data to your collection. This way your views don't have to know anything about each other which better conforms the Model and View separation.

Thus:

```
//the grid view
define(['backbone', 'collections/timetracks', 'views/timetracks/item'], function (Backbone, instanceTimeTracksCollection, TimeTrackView) {
    var TimeTrackGrid = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            //start listening to models being added
            this.listenTo(instanceTimeTracksCollection, "add", this.render)
        },
        render: function () {
            //render your view
            return this;
        }
    });
    return TimeTrackGrid;

});


//and the form view
define(['backbone', 'collections/timetracks'], function (Backbone, instanceTimeTracksCollection) {
    //...............
    //next comes my issue:
    create: function () {
        var data = //get the data from the form
            instanceTimeTracksCollection.add(data) //if you have defined a model on your collection, backbone will automatically instantiate the model
    }
});


//and you app -> notice the reference to the collection definition
requirejs(['backbone','views/timetracks/new','views/timetracks/list', 'collections/timetrackcollection'],
    function(Backbone, newTimeTrackForm, timeTracksGrid) {
        var instanceTimeTracksCollection = new TimeTracksCollection();
        var grid = new timeTracksGrid({model : instanceTimeTracksCollection});
        var formView = new newTimeTrackForm(model : instanceTimeTracksCollection);
    });
```

EDIT=========================================================

fetch the config here

```
requirejs(['backbone','views/timetracks/new','views/timetracks/list'],
    function(Backbone, newTimeTrackForm, timeTracksGrid) {
        var grid = new timeTracksGrid();
        var formView = new newTimeTrackForm();
        var collection = new Collection();
        collection.fetch()
    });
```

change your view to:

```
define(['backbone','collections/timetracks', 'views/timetracks/item'], function(Backbone, timeTracksCollection, TimeTrackView){
    var TimeTrackGrid = Backbone.View.extend({
            //....
            initialize: function(){
                _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'generateTimeTracks', 'appendTimeTrack');
                // maybe backbone does not fire the add event after fetch
                // I believe it does, but I might be mistaken. You will have to look         that up
                this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
                this.render();
            }
            //model is passed to the render method by backbone
            render: function(model){
                $(this.el).html("<table border='1'></table>");
                $('table', this.el).append(new TimeTrackView({model : model}).render().el);
           },
           //unused now
           generateTimeTracks : function(){
                var self = this;
                // backbone has underscore build in
                // so use this instead
                this.collection.each(function(item){
                     //do something with item
                }
                _(this.collection.models).each(function(item){ 
                    self.appendTimeTrack(item);
                }, this);
           },
           //unused now
           appendTimeTrack: function(item){
                var timeTrackView = new TimeTrackView({
                    model: item
                });
                $('table', this.el).append(timeTrackView.render().el);
           }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for you answer and sorry for my late reply, I was very busy with other stuff and now I'm returning to my first steps on node.js. 

I took your advice and I make an instance of the constructor separately. Unfortunately now I'm facing a new issue with the "Add" event. The problem is when the timetracks view is rendered, when this happens I'm FETCHING the collection of models from the server,  the fetching is casing sort of overlapping of triggered "add" events. Above there is a new update of my code.

Comment: so on ead add, you'll fetch the whole collection? Doesn't seem right to me. see mmy edit for an update.